# Re-factoring between projcets: bringing all the right classes over at once

Tags: refactoring

I am creating a new Android project that my team wants to port a specific set of classes from another project. We want three activities, but each activity requires a heavy load of fragments, util classes, xml, etc. and I have spent hours moving things over one class at a time. This is becoming very tedious and I feel like there should be a better way, but my initial efforts to find something have been unfruitful. Any ideas how to do this better/faster?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apart from a cleaner design in the first place?

 But for next time: Try to keep dependencies minimal when porting the code. If it has the quality of a module, abstract it into a module and use it in both projects.

For now, I'd just go with an IDE that tries to resolve dependencies in real time and informs you about everything that's missing. If your project is not one of those legacy behemoths where absolutely everything is dependent everything, that approach is actually promising. If you indeed have such a monster in front of you- kill it. Whether through refactoring (abstract stuff, design interfaces and modules) or through rewriting, almost everything is better than copying an essentially unmaintainable codebase.

Comment: Thanks! You've at least given me some confidence going forward that there's no cutting corners here. I'll keep on plugging away.